# How to mock generic interface in vb.net using Rhino Mocks

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I have an interface that looks something like this:

```
ISomeInterface(Of ClassA, ClassB)
```

Can I mock this interface using VB.NET and Rhino Mocks? If so, how? If not, which alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution:

```
        <TestInitialize()>
    Public Sub TestInitialize()
        _myStub= MockRepository.GenerateStub(Of ISomeInterface(Of ClassA, ClassB))()
        _controller = New MyController(_myStub)
    End Sub

    <TestMethod()>
    Public Sub SomeMethodCallsMyStubOtherMethod()
        Dim someObject As New SomeObject() With {.Title = "TEST"}
        _myStub.Stub(Of SomeObject)(Function(x) x.GetSomeObject()).Return(someObject)
        Dim result As JsonResult = _controller.SomeMethod()
        Dim someResult As SomeObject = result.Data

        Assert.IsNotNull(someResult)
        Assert.AreEqual(someResult.Title, someObject.Title)
    End Sub
```